PapaParse incorrectly handles empty rows, so that it affects headers?


const csvString2 = "a;b\r\n1;2\r\n3;4\r\n";
const csvArray2 = Papa.parse(csvString2, { header: true }).data;
console.log("csvArray2", csvArray2);

const csvString3 = "a;b\r\n1;2\r\n3;4";
const csvArray3 = Papa.parse(csvString3, { header: true }).data;
console.log("csvArray3", csvArray3);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.4.1/papaparse.min.js" integrity="sha512-dfX5uYVXzyU8+KHqj8bjo7UkOdg18PaOtpa48djpNbZHwExddghZ+ZmzWT06R5v6NSk3ZUfsH6FNEDepLx9hPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



gives
csvArray2 [ { 'a;b': '1;2' }, { 'a;b': '3;4' }, { 'a;b': '' } ]
csvArray3 [ { a: '1', b: '2' }, { a: '3', b: '4' } ]

skipEmptyLines: true
would solve the problem, but why the empty rows affects headers ?

If you don't provide a delimiter, PapaParse tries to guess the delimiter in line https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/papaparse.js#L1095
If there is no empty line at the end, it can successfully guess the delimiter as ;. With this additional empty line, the guess fails and the default delimiter , is used.
Roughly speaking, the guess system works like this. PapaParse checks the result for each possible delimiter and chooses the delimiter with the best result. ; is not the best result, because it finds one delimiter in the first two lines and no delimiter in the last line. A delimiter needs an average field count >1.99 to be a valid guess. ; has two fields in the first two rows and one field in the third row. That's 5/3 = 1.66 < 1.99.
https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/papaparse.js#L1342
